# JS Scipt that detects if the message is in English or not

Tags: javascript, scripting

I need to make a script that detects if a message that was sent by someone is in English and not in any other languages , I was thinking to create a DB with all the English words but I think that is gonna be too heavy for a bot and some people might spell the words wrong

Answer (score 0):

Implementing your own solution for this is almost never what you want to be doing. My first step would be to look into an existing npm package like [languagedetect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/languagedetect). There are likely also multiple APIs that are designed for this purpose, here's a few:

- [detectlanguage.com](https://detectlanguage.com/)
- [Microsoft's Text Analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-language-detection)
- [AWS' 'Detect the Dominant Language'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/how-languages.html)

Comment: Would Google Translate API be a suitable choice ?

Comment: Yep [https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/detecting-language](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/detecting-language)